# If i give HTML in search field design is breaking - PHP

Tags: php, html

Consider i am having a web page with a search field in it

When i give the following keyword and click search my design is breaking: Below is the keyword.

```
<table><tr><td>image asset</td></tr></table>
```

**I used strip_tags**

But it doesn't helps. It only helps in the below case: That is no space between the keyword. If i give the below it's working fine.

```
<table><tr><td>imageasset</td></tr></table>
```

What should i do to overcome this issue ?

Any idea will be helpful and grateful..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: "design is breaking" is insufficient information to understand the problem, and a 1x1 table is nonsense, use a table only if you have tabular data.

Comment: pls so your searching php code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issue elsewhere.

```
strip_tags('<table><tr><td>image asset</td></tr></table>'); //> returns: image asset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or htmlentities() functions to convert HTML markup into a form that won't break your own markup when you try to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you highlight the searched word somehow (incorrectly) with e.g. a breaking div (div:block)? Or otherwise replace search word/code when showing the results?